# Image slider positioning in responsive design

Tags: html, css, image, slider, responsive

I am *totally* new to web design and am in the process of teaching myself as I go, as a result of promising to try and build a new website for someone.

I have followed tutorials to create a responsive design, all seemed to be going well until I added an image slider plugin ([Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)).

This works great, but I can't seem to work out positioning with it, so that the div below (just some social media buttons), sits beneath it rather than behind it.

I have been trying for over two days and can't seem to get to the bottom of it. I just want the div to sit beneath the image slider and be visible when users scroll down. I have managed to fix it to the bottom of the page, but this isn't what I want as it leaves white space when the page is resized and disappears at full screen.

I would so appreciate any advice. Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <title>Lamorran House Gardens</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    <!--Include JQUery-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!--Include Cycle2-->
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <!--centre slideshow-->
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.center.js"></script>
    <!--twitter-->
    <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="style-logo" src="images/Logo.png" alt="Lamorran Logo">
                <nav class="style-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Visitor info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedding Hire</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lamorran Lodge</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="column">

                <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-center-horz=true
                     data-cycle-center-vert=true data-cycle-speed=2000
                     data-cycle-overlay-template="{{title}}">
                    <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="images/image1_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                    <img src="images/image5_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                    <img src="images/image_3_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                    <img src="images/image2_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                    <img src="images/image_4_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                    <img src="images/image6_with_text.jpg" alt="Garden image" data-cycle-title="A garden window onto the sea">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>
    <div class="logo-box">
        <a href="http://www.greatgardensofcornwall.co.uk" class="greatgardens"><img src="images/great-gardens-logo.png" alt="Visit the Great Gardens of Cornwall Website" width="80" height="80"></a>
        <a href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186244-d188844-Reviews-Lamorran_House_Garden-St_Mawes_Roseland_Peninsula_Cornwall_England.html" class="tripadvisor"><img src="images/black-tripadvisor-icon-28.png" alt="Visit our page on Trip Advisor" width="50" height="50"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/lamorrangarden" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false" data-show-count="false">Follow @lamorrangarden</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

header{ padding: 32px;
    background-color: #119F96;
}

.row:before, .row:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}

.style-logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100;
}

.style-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.style-nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFFFCC;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px;
}

.cycle-slideshow { width: 100%;   }

.cycle-slideshow img { width: 100% }

/* overlay */
.cycle-overlay { 
    font-family:"old-standard";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#FFFFCC;
    opacity: none;
    padding: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: lighter;
    position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 600;
    background:#119F96; color:#FFFFCC; padding: 15px; opacity: 0.7;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.logo-box {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo-box img 
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.twitter-follow-button{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*Tablet view*/
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .style-nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .style-nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .cycle-overlay {
        text-align: center;
    }   
}

/*Desktop view*/
@media (min-width: 1024px){
    .style-logo{
        float: left;
    }
    .style-nav{
        float: right;
    }
    .cycle-overlay {
        text-indent: 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .logo-box {
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #FFFFCC;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've moved your HTML/CSS into the question itself and edited a bit for whitespace.